# ParcelJS does not bundle imported js library

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, parceljs, cloudflare-workers

I have a simple NodeJS app (A Cloudflare Worker).

In the main typescript file (`index.ts`) I import the handler module which has this as the first line:
`const Monitor = import('ping-monitor')`

`ping-monitor` is a dependency in package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "ping-monitor": "^0.6.2"
  }
```

Now when I run `parcel build src/index.ts` the output in the dist has:
`var $1ZQrD$pingmonitor = require("ping-monitor");`

So the contents of `ping-monitor` are not bundled properly. And when I try to run this locally via `wrangler dev` (output is `dist/worker.js`) it complains: `Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined`.

How can I tell ParcelJS to bundle `ping-monitor` inside the output?

Comment: what syntax is this? `const Monitor = import('ping-monitor')`.... Shouldn't it be `const Monitor = require('ping-monitor')`?

Comment: I'm not sure. The linter was complaining about `require` so had to use `import` there

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By default, parcel won't bundle any dependencies for nodejs build targets. If you want to bundle all dependencies you can use the `includeNodeModules` option (see [docs](https://parceljs.org/features/targets/#includenodemodules)), like this:

```
{
   ...
   "main": "dist/worker.js",
   "targets": {
      "main": {
         "includeNodeModules": true
      }
   }
}
```

(You can also specify "whitelist" of modules to include).