# Importing jQuery with Parcel JS

Tags: parceljs

I am trying to create a library using parceljs and after npm run watch, i am getting

Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "social-tagger",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "source": "src/index.ts",
  "main": "dist/main.js",
  "module": "dist/module.js",
  "scripts": {
    "watch": "parcel watch",
    "build": "parcel build"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@yaireo/tagify": "^4.12.0",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@parcel/packager-ts": "^2.6.2",
    "@parcel/transformer-typescript-types": "^2.6.2",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.5.14",
    "parcel": "^2.6.2",
    "typescript": "^4.7.4"
  }
}
```

**src/social.ts**

```
import * as jQuery from 'jquery';
```

How to properly import jQuery

**Output From Inspect Element**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Fixed it with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70162144/parceljs-does-not-bundle-imported-js-library, full package.json is below

Answer (score 0):

Added Targets to package.json

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "social-tagger",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "source": "src/index.ts",
  "main": "dist/main.js",
  "module": "dist/module.js",
  "scripts": {
    "watch": "parcel watch",
    "build": "parcel build"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@yaireo/tagify": "^4.12.0",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@parcel/packager-ts": "^2.6.2",
    "@parcel/transformer-typescript-types": "^2.6.2",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.5.14",
    "parcel": "^2.6.2",
    "typescript": "^4.7.4"
  },
  "targets":{
    "main": {
       "includeNodeModules": true
    }
 }
}
```

Create a file named jquery.ts

**jquery.ts**

```
import jquery from "jquery";

export default ((window as any).jQuery = jquery);
```

Dont import jquery instead import from jquery.ts

**social.ts**

```
import './jquery';
```